First field gets cleared (if time field) in QGIS Attribute Table
I recently noticed a strange bahavior in QGIS (currently working with version 3.34-7):
When the first field of a shapefile is named "time" (I regularly work with GPX files exported to shapefiles), selecting a feature (when editing is started) in the attribute table clears the field "time" unless I press Esc just after selecting the feature.
It seems like QGIS is always "starting to edit" the first field, after selecting a feature (is this a bug or a feature?) and if the first field is named "time" it can get catastrophic because the field gets cleared (unless you put in a new date).

Can you share the properties of your layer? Especially the settings in Layer properties > Attributes Form > "time" field. Maybe there are constraints set for that field which lead to that behaviour.
